# I am on Carrier-Grade NAT/NAT444 and port forwarding works. How?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, nat, isp

I cannot seem to get my head around this. My ISP very recently put me on CGN/NAT444 which means I should not be able to make customized port forwarding, but to my surprise I can. I tested it with built-in router UPnP protocol and it works.

How is it possible for my ISP to allow me to port forward on a huge NAT of theirs? How incoming connections knows my specific router on the internet in the first place?

Comment: How do you know you are actually on CGNAT?

Comment: @user218076 my WAN IP is 10.64.89.76 that’s why.

Comment: Do you use your own router, or is it provided by the ISP?

Comment: @grawity It’s ISP router.

Comment: How are you testing it? Are you trying to access your wan IP and port from a different location? Or are you on the same network?